# Trying to extract EXIF, resize tif, then reinsert EXIF

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff, exif

Python novice.  I'm trying to retain EXIF tags for a tif image I want to resize and have tried using PIL to do this.  I seem to be able extract the EXIF data and resize but the resized file does not have the EXIF tags showing the same way that I see them in the source file.  I do not see any tags listed in the resized file the way I see information for the source using Windows properties attribute on the images.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
from PIL import Image, TiffImagePlugin
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

# Open the TIFF image file
image = Image.open("source.tiff")
image.load()  # This is required for working with TIFF files

# Extract the EXIF data
exif_data = {}
for tag_id in image.tag_v2.keys():
    tag = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
    value = image.tag_v2[tag_id]
    exif_data[tag] = value

# Remove the EXIF data from the image
image_info = image.info.copy()
image_without_exif = Image.new(image.mode, image.size)
image_without_exif.putdata(list(image.getdata()))
image_without_exif.info = image_info

# Resize the image
new_size = (800, 600)
resized_image = image_without_exif.resize(new_size)

print(exif_data)
print(image.getexif())
print(image.tag_v2)

# Reinsert the EXIF data into the resized image
resized_image.save("resized.tiff", exif=exif_data, tiffinfo=image.tag_v2)
```

I'm printing a few different exif information for debugging and I'm seeing:

```
{'ImageWidth': 4112, 'ImageLength': 3008, 'BitsPerSample': (16,), 'Compression': 1, 'PhotometricInterpretation': 1, 'Make': 'Voyis', 'Model': '', 'StripOffsets': (1188,), 'Orientation': 1, 'YCbCrPositioning': 1, 'SamplesPerPixel': 1, 'RowsPerStrip': 3008, 'StripByteCounts': (24737792,), 'XResolution': 72.0, 'YResolution': 72.0, 'PlanarConfiguration': 1, 'GPSInfo': 1054, 'ResolutionUnit': 2, 'ExifOffset': 338, 65000: 391274, 65001: 4292914547, 'Software': 'ULS500API 6.0.2.9f10f6a9', 'NewSubfileType': 0}
{34665: 338, 34853: 1054, 256: 4112, 257: 3008, 258: 16, 259: 1, 262: 1, 271: 'Voyis', 272: '', 273: 1188, 274: 1, 531: 1, 277: 1, 278: 3008, 279: 24737792, 282: 72.0, 283: 72.0, 284: 1, 296: 2, 65000: 391274, 65001: 4292914547, 305: 'ULS500API 6.0.2.9f10f6a9', 254: 0}
{256: 4112, 257: 3008, 258: (16,), 259: 1, 262: 1, 271: 'Voyis', 272: '', 273: (1188,), 274: 1, 531: 1, 277: 1, 278: 3008, 279: (24737792,), 282: 72.0, 283: 72.0, 284: 1, 34853: 1054, 296: 2, 305: 'ULS500API 6.0.2.9f10f6a9', 65000: 391274, 34665: 338, 65001: 4292914547, 254: 0}
```

This information matches what I see for the source. I am guessing that I may be missing a formatting step on the write to destination but I am unable to figure out how this should look.

I am open to any Python based solution if PIL is not the best option.  Can someone lend a hand?  Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you shared your TIFF file! You'd probably need to use Dropbox or Google Drive.